# Como hacer If compacto con variables constante ( define() )? y como saber si se conecta a google.fonts.com

Tags: php

```
  define('FONTS_ONLINE',' <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Arimo:400,400i|Bree+Serif|Dosis:400,500|Oswald:400,500" rel="stylesheet">');

  define('FONTS_HOUSED','<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fonts.css">');
```

*LLamar a las variables constantes*

```
<?php if (FONTS_ONLINE) ? FONTS_ONLINE : FONTS_HOUSED ?>
```

Comment: Usted puede hacer una function para definir donde tienes que buscar a las fonts... tambien seria valido

Comment: eso es lo que busco amigo, me podrias enseñar

Comment: Bueno, claro hermano.

Comment: Yo hago en la forma que envie, pero no sé se es esto que quieres amigo

Comment: lo que hago es lo mismo, es como asignar a unavariable un valor

Comment: Si, pero en la forma que ust fez, no sé se seria el corecto, yo hago da forma que mostré a vos

Answer (score 0):

Yo hago de la seguiente forma:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function crear_fonts($type){
        switch($type){
            case 'local':
                $font = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"fonts/fonts.css\">";
                break;

            case 'google':
                $font = "<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Arimo:400,400i|Bree+Serif|Dosis:400,500|Oswald:400,500\" rel=\"stylesheet\">";
                break;
        }
        return $font;   
    }
?>
```

**Para anadir el font:**

```
<?php
    include("functions.php");

    echo crear_fonts('google'); // return font google
    echo crear_fonts('local'); // return font local
?>
```

Comment: el problema es que se ejecute a google fonts y si no se establese la conexion que use el fonts local  sabes como es

Comment: quien me ayuda en este problema

Comment: No hay manera de que sepamos si o no la conexión ...